# Accessing local file while inside a virtual environment

Tags: python

I need to be able to access credentials that are stored locally while I'm inside a virtual environment?

For example, while I'm here:

`(virtenv) ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:~$ pwd
/home/ubuntu`

I want to access data stored here:

`/Users/username/.aws/credentials`

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: are you in a virtual environment i.e. `virtualenv`, or a virtual machine? If the former, you can just browse there. If the latter, you'll have to do some sysadmin magic.

Comment: @Adam-Smith Both actually. Using code that's in a virtualenv to remote into an AWS box. I want the code that's running in the remote instance to be able to see my locally stored credentials. It sounds like the answer is "no **easy** way," which I kind of expected.

Comment: Or at least no easy *safe* way. You can easily copy your credentials over the wire to the AWS box, but it's less easy to ensure they haven't been compromised in the transfer.

Comment: Isn't that the bread and butter job of ssh/scp?

Comment: "Using code that's in a virtualenv to remote into an AWS box." Do you mean you copy code from local to the remote box and then run it there, or that your locally-running code does something like an ssh subprocess to do things on the remote instance?

Comment: @TomDalton I have personal credentials stored on my local machine that I don't want to copy into the remote machine for security reasons. I'm looking for a way for the remote machine to reference those credentials.